# multiple charts sliced from main chart in d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a main bar chart with 36 countries.

With the main chart, I'd like to render small multiple charts on same html. The small charts will contain each group, e.g. Western Europe, Central and Estern Europe, Northern Europe, North America and so forth. All charts including the main chart will shaffle bars when dropdown menu is selected.

My explanation may look confusing, but basically, what I'd like to do is like facetting in R ggplot.

I found this article: https://blog.scottlogic.com/2017/04/05/interactive-responsive-small-multiples.html

Alghough, it may work for my case, I'd like to avoid it because 1) I've rendered the main chart already (with dropdown linked), 2) want to learn general ways that can apply to different instances.

I came up with this stratege below:

1. multiple divs/svgs are made or one svg is divided,
2. each div or svg contain code to render a bar chart for each group (with filtered data)
3. link them to a dropdown

Because each div / svg will repeat the same code, the code will be redundantly long. I'm sure there are better ways.

What would be best way to work it out? Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I have a feeling your question may be closed for being too broad, but anyway... it's not clear from your explanation what the dropdown menu is doing - can you add your current code to the question? Are you planning on having a dropdown for each little chart? If you are creating numerous charts and you want to be able to dynamically filter them, dc.js may provide the functionality that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know my question was too broad. I just wanted to get some idea where to start looking for, like your dc.js advice. I will start looking at it

Comment: I think the visualisation that Id like to make is simpler than you think. Main chart with 36 countries and small 6 charts whith 6 countries for each. All charts look same sharing the aame structure except for data filtered. They all link to one dropdown (changing value) interacting in a same way at the same time.

Comment: What have you written so far? It might be possible to do a bit of cut 'n' paste and get what you want without having to write out too much more new stuff.

Comment: The point is, the small charts doesnt need to be linked to each other.

Comment: I dont have a code for the part yet. The question was more to look for concepts where to start looking into.

Comment: how about this: http://bl.ocks.org/officeofjane/7315455

Comment: Thanks for the reference. That's the concept that I was looking for. One thing that can be updated based on that is to change scale depending on data bound to each svg compared to the example where keeps scale same for all svg. I'm looking for it but do you have an idea?

Comment: You should be able to just scale your axes according to the data set.

Comment: Thanks for taking time for this. I figured out how to do. Thanks a lot!